# Issue with JavaFX second scene/stage creation

Tags: java, javafx, scene, stage

I've been having troubles generating a second stage/scene in my program. I have a first stage/scene that generates at launch, works perfectly with a working button. It is in it's own class and executes at the beginning.

Further along in the program I have a method that I was hoping to launch my next stage from. I had created another class below for the generation of my second stage, and placed the constructor within this method. When the method is executed, a stage is being created, but the scene isn't showing anything, just the stage with the proper title. I've tried adding in simple buttons, labels with text, but nothing shows. Not really sure what could be the cause, but after fiddling for awhile I decided to request some help from you guys. Given my limited knowledge of JavaFX, I was wondering if the first stage is causing problems for the second one? I leave it open and running, should I close it before this second executes? Or is there a better way to create a second stage without creating a whole new class? Is the construction of the secondScene class a possible problem?

Let me know, thanks!

EDIT: I have now added a runtime exception handler in, and it does trigger a runtime exception when this class is created. I'm still a bit new to Java, does this mean the problem lies within the class I've created? Or can it still be something earlier on in the code? I have still not been able to get the simple class to create inside this program effectively, so I'm unable to produce a minimum level of functionality here, but according to other people, the code does work when it stands alone.

```
public SecondScene() {

    Thread t = new Thread(new adminThread());
      t.setUncaughtExceptionHandler(new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {

         public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) {
            System.out.println(t + " throws exception: " + e);
         }
      });
      // this will call run() function
      t.start();

    Text textOutput = new Text(textToDisplay);
    BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane(textOutput);
    Scene secondScene = new Scene(borderPane, 400, 600);

    // New window (Stage)
    Stage secondWindow = new Stage();
    secondWindow.setTitle("Second Window");
    secondWindow.setScene(secondScene);

    secondWindow.show();
}

    public void setRunningText(String text){
        this.textToDisplay = text;
    }
```

}

class adminThread implements Runnable {

```
   public void run() {
      throw new RuntimeException();
   }
}
```

Comment: Do you get any exception? With a first look the stage should be shown. However could you create a MCVE where it doesn't work? Is the first stage somehow configured to be always on top or is modal?

Comment: The code is working fine for me. Create a [mcve] allowing us to reproduce the issue.

Comment: No exceptions are thrown. Before I had left the first stage running in the background, but I just reconfigured it to close prior to launching the second stage and the same issue occurs. So far I reconstructed it as its own method to launch, but no matter where I launch it same problem happens. Stage gets created but no scene. I can't seem to find a base point where this code will work within the program I've written.

Comment: "Stage gets created but no scene" do you mean the window is shown but no content? I tried it out and it works just as expected with your code, called within an eventhandler. Have you installed an UncaughtExceptionHandler that may ignore any exception?

Comment: Window is shown but no content inside. I'll look up how to setup a uncaught exception handler and see if that triggers anything.

Comment: Partial Success: I was able to get the window to show properly when creating the class outside of the method I had it running within. The problem seems to be when running anything within that method. Given that I know where the problem lies, I will try to find a roundabout way to resolve this problem now. Thanks for all responses!

Comment: What method did you use to create your class? Was is it inside a JavaFX Eventhandler and triggered by an action in the UI?

Comment: It wasn't inside the JavaFX event handler. As I've been researching this issue, I think I've realized a larger problem in the way that I've created and structured the program. I'm going to create another SO request with an update on the issue now that I've moved most of the logic over to the initial Application thread. Thanks for your response.